# $http mocking is not persistant across tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine

Is this set up for `$http` mocking?

For some reason I am getting this error:

> Uncaught Error: Unexpected request: GET http://

describe('DataService tests', function () {

```
    var errorUrl = "/ErrorReturningURL";
    var successUrl = "/SuccessReturningURL";

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('app'));

    beforeEach(angular.mock.inject(function ($httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.when('GET', successUrl).respond('all good!');
        $httpBackend.when('GET', errorUrl).respond(404, '');
    }));

    it('should call the callbackError when http returns error', inject(function (DataService, $httpBackend) {
        var successCallback = jasmine.createSpy();
        var errorCallback = jasmine.createSpy();

        $httpBackend.expectGET(errorUrl);

        DataService.getData(errorUrl, successCallback, errorCallback);

        $httpBackend.flush();

        expect(errorCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));


}
```

)
;

service(simplified):

```
app.service('DataService', function ($http, $parse) {

  this.getData = function (url, callbackSuccess, callbackError) {

      $http.get(url).success( function (data) {

        callbackSuccess( processedData );
      }).error( function (error) {
        callbackError(error);
      });

  };

});
```

Comment: please post your whole spec + DataService. where `successUrl` / `errorUrl` come from?

Comment: @IlanFrumer ok have done :)

Answer (score 2):

#### original `$http` ?

- I assume you included `angular-mocks.js` in your `karma.js.conf` file.
- **angular-mocks** overrides the original $httpBackend , so it is impossible to do real requests.
- `$httpBackend mock` has a synchronous API but it must integrate with your asynchronous application.
- The `flush()` method is the connecting link between asynchronous applications and synchronous tests.

#### From [$httpBackend docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock.$httpBackend):

> #### Flushing HTTP requests
>
> The $httpBackend used in production, always responds to requests with responses asynchronously. If we preserved this behavior in unit testing, we'd have to create async unit tests, which are hard to write, follow and maintain. At the same time the testing mock, can't respond synchronously because that would change the execution of the code under test. **For this reason the mock $httpBackend has a flush() method, which allows the test to explicitly flush pending requests and thus preserving the async api of the backend**, while allowing the test to execute synchronously

#### You must call `flush()` to actually make the request:

```
 $httpBackend.expectGET(errorUrl);

 DataService.getData(errorUrl, successCallback, errorCallback);
  
 $httpBackend.flush();

 expect(errorCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

Comment: yeah I do, when flush is called I get an error Uncaught Error: Unexpected request: GET http://..

Comment: I updated my answer. I thought you know you must also use `$httpBackend.expectGET`, please read the docs.